# Is there a typical Easter greeting in Latin?

Tags: christianity, calendarium

The typical Easter greetings are different in different languages.
In some languages it's "Happy Easter" or "Good Easter", while some say "Christ has risen".
Any of these phrases could be translated to Latin and probably understood.
But what would be an idiomatic choice?
Do we have attestations of one or more preferred Easter greetings in Latin?

Comment: Resurrexit sicut dixit comes to mind. I'd look in papal urbi et orbi Easter greetings. I hope I'll have a few minutes for that next Monday

Comment: I'll have to expand on this if possible but Wikipedia has an article on "Paschal greeting".

Comment: @MattGutting [So it seems.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschal_greeting) It'd be good to see there's more reliable proof for the phrases suggested there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be no standard Easter greeting in Latin, but rather several established/attested forms of announcing the Good News of the Resurrection. Good authoritative sources for this kind of Easter greeting are the messages from the popes with occasion of every year's Easter sunday.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbi_et_Orbi#Greetings_in_different_languages) confirms that the papal greeting for the *Urbi et Orbi* blessing on Easter is different every year, and links to the [2012 address by Pope Benedict XVI](http://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/it/bollettino/pubblico/2012/04/08/0209/00469.html). In that occasion the greeting was a quotation of the [Easter Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victimae_paschali_laudes):

> Surrexit Christus spes mea. Alleluja!

In 2011 it was

> Surrexit Dominus vere! Alleluja!

from the [Regina Coeli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regina_caeli).

Another example is St. John Paul II's greeting in 2004, who chose

> [Resurrexit. Alleluja!](http://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/it/bollettino/pubblico/2004/04/11/0178/00556.html) and [Surrexit Christus. Alleluja!](http://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/it/bollettino/pubblico/2004/04/11/0177/00555.html)

Other forms include *Christus resurrexit!* [(Benedict XVI, 2006)](http://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/it/bollettino/pubblico/2006/04/16/0192/00555.html), *Christus surrexit, venite et videte* [(Francis, 2014)](http://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/it/bollettino/pubblico/2014/04/20/0288/00632.html) and even the Greek *Cristòs anèsti! – Alethòs anèsti!* [(Francis, 2014b,](http://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/it/bollettino/pubblico/2014/04/21/0289/00633.html) transliterated in Latin alphabet in the source).